# I encountered an error when using break function in PAF loop tag

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

```
break attribute is not mentioned in loop tag
```

How to use break function in loop tag?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use break Variable attribute.
Eg:

```
<activity id="Loop_Tag">
    <loop startIndex="0" lastIndex="10" increment="2" counterVar="i" breakVariable="j" desc="LOOP TAG" expResult="Loop from 0 to 10 incrementing by 2" >
          <wait time="1000" desc="WAIT TAG" expResult="Application should wait for 1 secs" ></wait>
          <if valGroupIds="VerifyBreak" desc="IF TAG for Validation" expResult="j should be true if the condition pass" >
                     <variable keyName="j" value="true" desc="VARIABLE TAG" expResult="j equals to true" ></variable>
          </if>
    </loop>

</activity>
<valGroup groupId="VerifyBreak">
          <validate variable="i" condition="equals" value="6" passMsg="PASSED --breakVariable" failMsg="FAILED --breakVariable" desc="VALIDATE TAG" expResult="VALIDATE the validation" >
                     </validate>
</valGroup>
```